# Example: "Harry=human165". I want to seach a pattern in every line and insert preceding word twice separated by '=$' in another file

Tags: regex, unix

```
source file  --testfile.txt
Harry=human165
Larry=human166
--outputfile.txt
Harry=$Harry
Larry=$Larry
```

The method i am using is

```
sed '/[A-Za-z].*[=].*/' testfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

not able to formulate code

```
Any help or link is appreciated..
```

thanks

Comment: `sed: -e expression #1, char 17: missing command`. You have not even tried a [substitution command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html), why?

Comment: `sed 's/^\([[:alpha:]]*\)=.*/\1=$\1/' testfile.txt > outputfile.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do this by listing lines in file A via `cat`, filtering interesting lines with `grep`, `sed`-replacing input strings into a form I want, and appending `>>` altered lines to file B. For example:

```
cat filea | grep '=' | sed -E 's/^([A-Za-z]+).*/\1=\$\1/' >> fileb
```

Comment: Thanks it worked ... modified a little as i needed _ too.
cat filea | grep '=' | sed -E 's/^([A-Za-z_]+).*/\1=\$\1/' >> fileb